# Pyplot: Position of cursor not shown

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I make subplots in pyplot, then the position of the cursor is not correctly shown, as you can see in the image below (cursor was somewhere in the upper right subplot (same behavior experienced with all the other subplots), but when I made the screenshot, the cursor wasn't there (I use Win10)):
[image]
The value between `[]` is the correct color value, but the `x` and `y` values are not shown. This happens only when I use subplots.
Here's the code that produced that picture:

```
def plot_subplots(lam, t):
    # lam: list of 4 lambda values, t fixed
    f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
    ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = ax
    ax = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]
    # get X and K (both equidistant arrays)

    for k, l in enumerate(lam):
        # get the color array husimi
        p = ax[k].pcolorfast(X, K, husimi, cmap='jet')
        ax[k].set_title(r'$\lambda='+str(l)+'$')

    ax1.set_ylabel(r'$k$')
    ax3.set_ylabel(r'$k$')
    ax1.set_yticks([min(K), 0, max(K)])
    ax1.set_yticklabels([r'$-\pi$', r'$0$', r'$\pi$'])
    ax3.set_yticks([min(K), 0, max(K)])
    ax3.set_yticklabels([r'$-\pi$', r'$0$', r'$\pi$'])
    ax3.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
    ax4.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
    ax3.set_xticks([min(X), 0, max(X)])
    ax4.set_xticks([min(X), 0, max(X)])
    ax3.set_xticklabels([r'$'+str(min(X))+'$', r'$0$', r'$'+str(max(X))+'$'])
    ax4.set_xticklabels([r'$'+str(min(X))+'$', r'$0$', r'$'+str(max(X))+'$'])
    f.suptitle(r'$t_2='+str(t)+'$')
```

I use Python 3.4.3 64Bit and Matplotlib 1.5.2, if this matters. Does someone spot an error in the code that produces this behavior or is this just some bug of `plt.pcolorfast`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with subplots. It's also not a bug or error in `pcolorfast`.

The reason, no numbers are shown is that you manually set the xticklabels. Using `ax.set_xticklabels` overwrites the Formatter of the axes and creates a fixed formatter. The problem may become obvious if you were setting `ax.set_xticklabels(["apple", "banana", "cherry"])`; which value would you have in between apple and banana?!

So the idea is of course not to use `set_xticklabels` and thereby not using a fixed formatter. Instead, one may use a `FuncFormatter` with a function that returns a value for every possible input and only makes sure, that e.g. `np.pi` is formatted as `π`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
Z = np.random.normal(size=np.array(X.shape)-1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

pc = ax.pcolorfast(X,Y,Z)
ax.set_yticks([-np.pi, 0, np.pi])

def fmt(x,pos):
    if np.isclose([np.abs(x)],[np.pi]):
        if x>0: return r'$\pi$'
        else: return r'$-\pi$'
    else:
        return "%g" % x
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))

fig.colorbar(pc, ax=fig.axes)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Good to know that I'm kind of destroying something when setting the labels in that simple way.